# Вывод информации из базы данных MYSQL PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Есть четыре таблицы "Тип работ", "Отдел", "Задачи", "Подзадачи". У каждого типа работ может быть несколько отделов, у каждого отдела может быть несколько задач, и у каждой задачи может быть несколько отделов. Надеюсь объяснил понятно. Все это надо вывести в виде списка.

С горем пополам получилось вывести "Тип работ" -> "Отдел"

```
    <?php
    include('config2.php');
    $sql_works = "SELECT * FROM otdel,works,exam WHERE works.id = otdel.id_type and exam.id_otd = otdel.id_type ";
    $result = mysql_query($sql_works);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
          $data[$row['name_work']][] = $row['name_otdel'];
          $data2[$row['name_otdel']][] = $row['name_exam'];
    }

        echo "<ul>";
        foreach ($data as $name_work => $name_otdel) {
              echo "<li>" . $name_work . "</li>";
              echo "<ul><li>" . implode('</li><li>',$name_otdel) . "</li></ul>";  

        }    
         foreach ($data2 as $name_otdel => $name_exam) {
              echo "<li>" . $name_otdel . "</li>";
              echo "<ul><li>" . implode('</li><li>',$name_exam) . "</li></ul>"; 



    } 
    echo "</ul>";


?>
```

А вот как вывести "Тип работ" -> "Отдел" -> "Задачи" не знаю... 
Сейчас это выглядит вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В чем хитрость двойного цикла? Используйте один `while () { ... }`.

Comment: @visman Так все равно не выходит)

Comment: @visman А почему же не нужен второй цикл?

Comment: @АртёмРумянцев, а почему он нужен? ;)

Comment: @АртёмРумянцев, заставлять пользователей ru.SO вглядываться в вашу картинку и пытаться понять что же не так, это, как минимум, не вежливо.

Comment: @dmitriysimushev Сильно извиняюсь, просто очень хочу разобраться) Просто сижу очень долго, искал искал и не нашел) Решил залезть в SO.

Comment: @АртёмРумянцев, вам бы ознакомиться с PDO или mysqli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно ты хотел что то подобное?

```
<?php

include('config2.php');
$sql_works = "SELECT * FROM otdel,works,exam WHERE works.id = otdel.id_type and exam.id_otd = otdel.id_type ";
$result = mysql_query($sql_works);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $data[$row['name_work']][$row['name_otdel']][] = $row['name_exam'];
}
echo "<ul>";
foreach ($data as $name_work => $otdel_array) {
    echo "<li>" . $name_work . "</li>";
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($otdel_array as $otdel_name => $exam_names) {
        echo "<li>" . $otdel_name . "</li>";
        echo "<ul><li>" . implode('</li><li>', $exam_names) . "</li></ul>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: Да, спасибо! Еще один вопросец... Как сделать чтобы выводились записи у которых нет child'ов?

Comment: В селекте тогда надо использовать LEFT JOIN [Mysql JOIN](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/JOIN.html)

SELECT * 
FROM works
LEFT JOIN otdel ON works.id = otdel.id_type
LEFT JOIN exam ON otdel.id_type = exam.id_otd

Таким образом будут показываться записи work у которых может не быть otdel и соотвесвенно otdel у которых нету exam

Comment: Слушай, а еще вопросец, как мнe в otdel_name вывести другие поля из таблицы otdel

Comment: ну есть много вариантов решения данный ситуации.
Тот который у тебя сейчас никак не будет предусматривать этой.

Comment: 1. ты можешь отсортировать свой селект (ORDER BY name_work, name_otdel, name_exam) и в while идти по каждой строке и открывать/закрывать ul при смене этих значений в строке, соответсвенно ты будешь иметь доступ к остальным значениям из строки

2. создать ещё один массив в котором будет информация по конкретному отделу

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант

```
$sql_works = "SELECT * FROM otdel,works WHERE works.id = otdel.id_type";
$result = mysql_query($sql_works);

$data = [];
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      $data[$row['name_work']][] = $row['name_otdel'];
}
if($data) {
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($data as $name_work => $name_otdel) {
          echo "<li>" . $name_work . "</li>");
          echo "<ul><li>" . implode('</li><li>, '$name_otdel) . "</li></ul>";       
    }    
    echo "</ul>";
} else {
    // нет результатов
}
```

Можно и в один цикл, но код не очень красивый

Comment: Попробовал данный код. Выдает ошибку Cannot use a scalar value as an array вот здесь $result[$row['name_work']][] = $row['name_otdel']; и ошибку Invalid argument supplied for foreach() вот здесь foreach ($result as $name_work => $name_otdel) {

Comment: Потому что код немного кривой, поправил

Comment: @korytoff Простите, а третий уровень делать так же? То есть будет foreach в foreache?

Comment: @АртёмРумянцев Какой третий уровень? В древовидная структура нужна что-ли? Тогда в первом цикле формируйте другую структуру массива и все. Вы изучали php?

Comment: @korytoff Просто мне нужно сделать дерево из четырех таблиц то есть  дальше у name_otdel еще подуровень из другой таблицы

Comment: @АртёмРумянцев внесите правку в свой вопрос и задайте его предметно

Comment: @korytoff Есть четыре таблицы "Тип работ", "Отдел", "Задачи", "Подзадачи". У каждого типа работ может быть несколько отделов, у каждого отдела может быть несколько задач, и у каждой задачи может быть несколько отделов. Надеюсь объяснил понятно. Все это надо вывести в виде списка.

Comment: @korytoff *У каждой задачи может быть несколько подзадач*

Comment: @АртёмРумянцев, никто вас в комментариях читать не будет, а же четко написал Внесите правку в свой вопрос. Такая ссылочка снизу вопроса с текстом "Правка"