# Вывод данных из нескольких таблиц в список PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Хочу спросить совета, как лучше реализовать вывод данного списка, через `PHP` и `Mysql`:

Раздел задач1

- Отдел 1
- Отдел 2
- Отдел 3

  - Наименование задачи
                            Поле 2
                            Поле 3
                            Поле 4
  - Наименование задачи
                            Поле 2
                            Поле 3
                            Поле 4

    - Подзадача
- Отдел 4

Раздел задач 2

- Отдел 1

  - Наименование задачи
                            Поле 2
                            Поле 3
                            Поле 4

    - Подзадача
- Отдел 2
- Отдел 3

  - Наименование задачи
                            Поле 2
                            Поле 3
                            Поле 4

    - Подзадача
- Отдел 4

Данные берутся из четырех таблиц БД:

1. Разделы задач(`id_razdel`, `name_razdel`)

2. Отделы (`id_otdel`, `name_otdel`, `id_razdel`)

3. Задачи (`id_exam`, `name_exam`, `performer`, `date_start`, `date_end`)

4. Подзадачи (`id_exam_child`, `name_exam_child`, `id_exam`)

Какой наилучший способ таково вывода можно использовать?

Пытаюсь выводить вот так:

```
<?php
connect();


$sql_works = "SELECT w.*, o.id_otdel, o.name_otdel, e.id_exam, e.name_exam FROM works w LEFT JOIN otdel o ON w.id = o.id_type LEFT JOIN exam e ON o.id_otdel = e.id_otd";
$result = mysql_query($sql_works);

$i = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    while (list ($key, $val) = each ($row)) {
        $data[$i][$key] = $val;
    }
    $i++;
}
echo "<ul>";
for ($i=0; $i<count($data); $i++) {
 echo '<li>'.$data[$i]["name_work"].'</li>';
 echo "<ul>";
 echo '<li>'.$data[$i]["name_otdel"].'</li>';
 echo "</ul>";
}

echo "</ul>";
mysql_close();
?>
```

Но выводятся дубликаты записей. То есть вместо того чтобы вывести 1 отдел с 4 задачами, выводится 4 одинаковых отдела, в которых в каждом по задаче.

Comment: Привет. Решение нашёл?

Answer (score 1):

Самый правильный способ обьединять таблицы в запросе - использовать Join

```
SELECT Отделы.name_otdel, Разделы_задач.name_razdel FROM Отделы
JOIN Разделы_задач
ON Разделы_задач.id_razdel = Отделы.id_razdel
```

Советую получше покопаться в sql, почитать литературы.
Кстати непонятно, как у вас задачи связанны с разделами задач.
Советую также почитать про шесть нормальных форм и нормализацию таблиц (до 3 формы нормализовывать надо уметь). Немного мозговзрывательно, но очень важно.

Вывод можно организовать следующим образом:

```
(Твой код подключения);
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row['имя поля'];
}
```

Естественно все это надо заправить html тегами по усмотрению.

[И пользуйся поиском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/456102/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-mysql-php?rq=1)

Comment: Разделы задач связаны с отделами) В каждом разделе задач есть свой отдел, который имеет свои задачи.